# How to execute flyway where in scripts & flyway services are stored in different repositories?

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

Since we have many applications & services that are going to leverage flyway, I have created 2 separate project repositories: 
 - migration-service, To store migration scripts.
 - flyway-service, to execute the scripts.

The Problem:

All teams are going to check in migration scripts in the **migration-service**(GITHUB), & then using **flyway-service** API they can run the migrations.

How can I always execute flyway-service with this design?

Technology used: Java, Springboot, flyway.

Please help!

Comment: By default, Flyway looks for migration scripts in the classpath under the `classpath:db/migration` directory. Putting the migration scripts in the service that executes Flyway would be convenient. Why separate them?

Comment: @ChinHuang - The reason is that we want to keep code & scripts in separate projects to avoid code changes in the flyway-service. Also considering the large volume of traffic on this service we don't want to deploy flyway service after every script commit as this would decrease the availability of service